# How to get constant value in view page which defined in app.js in Node.js

Tags: angularjs, ejs

At my app.js

```
var my_constant='Test'
```

I want to get it at my view page =>  my_constant

I don't want to pass my constant via my controller, want to get it direct at view.

Comment: You can't......

Comment: suppose I want to pass the similar constant's value at every view page than what is the better way?

Comment: Why would you do that? But anyway, it needs to be in the scope. You can put it in the root scope, and it would ba available everywhere. But that's usually a terrible idea: why would every view need to display the same thing?

Comment: I want to show a notification message at every view, it will be changed every 24 hours, so need to set value in a constant and show it at every page.

Comment: So, if your page uses 83 different views (1 header, 1 footer, 1 body, 80 components in a list), you want to display the same notification 83 times? Don't you rather want to display it once and only once, inside a single "notification" view, which would thus be the only view needing to access this value?

Comment: Thank @JB Nizet, it's a good idea, will implement it. perhaps in node scope of accessing a constant directly at view page is not exist.

Comment: I'm not sure what nodeJS has to do with this. AngularJS runs in the browser, not in NodeJS.

Comment: Yes, I am working in ejs template.